Can't file N600 for my child using my account
I'm trying to file form N600 for my child. Every where I checked, it says I should use my USCIS account to file for my minor child.
However, when I fill info about my child such as DoB, I get an error message saying "This account has already been verified with a different date of birth". This also happens for the A-number.
In other sections in the same form, it says 'if you are the parent of a minor filing, put in your info', which means this form IS supposed to be used for my minor using my account.
I can't find any other field to use for my child's date of birth. I can't submit the form before fixing this.
This is the form, field and error. It doesn't make sense to create an account for my little kid

These are the available sections.
I went through the entire application, no other page asks about my kids info.


Out of curiosity, why are you trying to get your child a certificate of citizenship instead of a passport?

A passport is enough for most cases. However, for some legal situations or if they lose their passport and we (the parents) are not around anymore, it might be tough for them to manage without anything that proves their citizenship.

I was finally able to chat with an agent in USCIS and surprisingly I was told to either create an account for my child or file N600 using mail.
So, it looks like the form is broken when submitting for your child using your account.
